# Oracle Indexing & SP Performance

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing, database-performance

Am trying to optimize some legacy SQL SPs against an Oracle view which is built from 6 tables, each joined by the same field, a numeric ID. Some of the tables in the view have an index which is solely this ID field, others do not.

If I create an index on the remaining tables in the view using this field only, and then perform the actual select query using this field as the sole parameter, will it improve performance notably? I can post the s.proc if its necessary as there may be other flaws in the SP which may not be solved by indexing alone. The query in question takes around 6 seconds to return 1 row, none of the tables contain a large amount of records, nothing over 100,000 records anyway.

Thanks in advance,

Scott

Comment: Is the ID field the first field in the index?  Is the index clustered?  Are you selecting all rows from the view, or a small number of rows based on ID?

Comment: The ID field is the first field in all the indexes that exist, like I say a couple of tables are missing an index on this field. Is it clustered, I don't know. I can't see a reference to clustered or non-clustered anywhere in the idx creation (using PL/SQL developer). The query should only ever return 1 row based on the supplied ID.

Comment: Scott, can you supply the explain plan the query generates? This will help to give you better advice on tuning the query.

Comment: Scott, go ahead and post the SP code too if you can, it might also be causing some of your performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure every table in the view has an index that starts with the id field. The index can conatain more fields as long as the id field is first.

If that doesn't help performance please post the select statement and the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID field is the first column in the indexes (or the only column) then adding indexes to the ID column of those remaining tables that need them will improve the query if you are returning a small number of rows.